# execute shell command with php

Tags: php, bash, shell

im trying to execute a bash script with a `php/html` button to wake my nas.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Wake NAS" name="zero" />
</form>
<?php
  if (isset($_POST["zero"])){
    #echo "Hello World!";
    shell_exec("/var/www/html/wakenas.sh &");
  }?>
```

"Hello World" is printed when button is pressed.
but code won't be executed.
the `wakenas.sh` looks like this and works if i execute it over shell

```
#!/bin/bash
etherwake -D "BC:5F:F4:09:E1:07"
echo "why!?!?!" > "/var/www/html/works.txt"
exit 1
```

`wakenas.sh` has all rights

Maybe you guys know why it wont be executed.

thanks in advance

Comment: How do you execute it over shell? `shell wakenas.sh`? Can you put the outputof `ls -l /path/to/wakenas.sh`

Comment: with `sh /path/to/wakenas.sh`

ls -l wakenas.sh:
`-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 126 Jun  4 12:47 wakenas.sh`

Comment: You script seems correct to me, try to `var_dump(shell_exec("/var/www/html/wakenas.sh &"));` to see whether it returns `NULL` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php#refsect1-function.shell-exec-returnvalues) and check you `/var/www/html/works.txt` file content

Comment: returned NULL
 
but found a little snippet in your link `2>&1` 

var_dump now returns: `string(590) "etherwake: This program must be run as root. The target station address is bc:5f:f4:9:e1:7. Packet is bc 5f f4 09 e1 07 bc 5f f4 09 e1 07 08 42 ff ff ff ff ff ff bc 5f f4 09 e1 07 bc 5f f4 09 e1 07 bc 5f f4 09 e1 07 bc 5f f4 09 e1 07 bc 5f f4 09 e1 07 bc 5f f4 09 e1 07 bc 5f f4 09 e1 07 bc 5f f4 09 e1 07 bc 5f f4 09 e1 07. SIOCGIFHWADDR on eth0 failed: Bad file descriptor /var/www/html/wakenas.sh: line 3: /var/www/html/hat_funktioniert.txt: Permission denied `

Comment: You should update your post with the output so that people who are able to help will see it

Comment: One last thing though, `ls -l /var/www/html/works.txt`

Comment: I'm guessing based on your use case, you're probably accessing the php via a web server like apache? Does the apache user (usually `nobody`, `www-data`, or `apache2`) have rights to execute `wakenas.sh`? Please be aware that if there is _any_ public access to the page, you should NOT give shell access/execute rights to your web server.

Answer (score 1):

The easy and secure way of executing your script is to put in sudoers. Assuming your Linux distribution is Debian base and user of who run the web server is `www-data`, then you can create a file e.g `/etc/sudoers.d/wakeup_ether`

```
Cmnd_Alias WAKE_UP_CMD = /var/www/html/wakenas.sh
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: WAKE_UP_CMD
```

Modify your script to prefix the command with `sudo`.

```
shell_exec("sudo /var/www/html/wakenas.sh &");
```

Reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

Answer (score 0):

From your dump:

```
etherwake: This program must be run as root.
```

when you execute wakenas.sh you probably are executing it as root. That's why it works.

Give the sudo permission (without password) to the user that your php server is running.

And change the wakenas.sh to:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo etherwake -D "BC:5F:F4:09:E1:07"
echo "why!?!?!" > "/var/www/html/works.txt"
exit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently published a project that allows PHP to obtain and interact with a real Bash shell (as root if requested), it solves the limitations of exec() and shell_exec(). Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

After downloading you would simply use the following code:

```
$shell    = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getShell('bash', true);
$return1  = $shell->exeCmd("etherwake -D \"BC:5F:F4:09:E1:07\"");
//the return will be a string containing the return of the command
echo $return1;
```